# How to get product thumbnails in shipping confirmation emails

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, email-templates

I just about have it but I can't find a way to get the thumbnail image. /template/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml I've tried these and none have worked:

```
<?php echo $_item->getThumbnail(); ?>

<?php echo $this->$_item->getThumbnail()); ?>

<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_item->getThumbnail()); ?>
```

I tried adding this to the top of the page

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
                ->load($_item->getProductId());
```

And this:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')  
                ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a way to do it.

Here's how in case anyone else wants to:

In `/template/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml` I added this to the top of the file:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
```

To get the image this:

```
<td>
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" width="65" height="95" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
</td>
```

In `/template/email/order/shipment/items.phtml` I added this:

```
<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Image') ?></th>
```

Here are the two files finished:

`/template/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml`

```
<?php

?>
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>

<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>

<tr>
<td>
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" width="65" height="95" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
</td>

    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px;">
        <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
        <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
        <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;"><?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?></dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item->getOrderItem())->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px;"><?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?></td>
</tr>
```

And `/template/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml`

```
<?php

?>
<?php $_shipment = $this->getShipment() ?>
<?php $_order    = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order): ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <thead>
        <tr>

        <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Image') ?></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_shipment->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
    <tbody<?php echo $i%2 ? ' bgcolor="#F6F6F6"' : '' ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please update for magento 2.3?